# Retrieving All items in a table with DynamoDB

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently in a web services class, and for the project I am working on, I decided to make a Web API using the .NET Core platform, with DynamoDB as the Database.

So far it has been a little tough getting Dynamo to work with .NET Core as I cannot seem to find too many articles on getting the two to work together. I am currently stuck on how to retrieve all items from a specific table.

I have been reading through the Dynamo documentation, and decided to go with the Object Persistence model.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
        services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    }
```

I inject the DynamoDB context in the Configure Services method of the Startup file. Then I inject it into the controller like this

```
    DynamoDBContext context;
    public ValuesController(IAmazonDynamoDB context)
    {
        this.context = new DynamoDBContext(context);
    }
```

Again, I am in no way an expert on these two technologies, so if there is a better way to do this please let me know.

I also have a simple model that I have been using that I got from the DynamoDB documentation.

```
[DynamoDBTable("AnimalsInventory")]
public class Item
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this article here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.QueryScan.html

it says you can just use the Query/Scan methods to retrieve items from the DB, but unfortunately those methods are not supported on the .NET Core platform. On .NET Core they are called QueryAsync and ScanAsync, and I thought maybe I could just call the method without any arguments and it would just retrieve any items in the table, but that did not work. It looks like the method specifically takes in some scan conditions, so I am not sure if I am using the wrong methods, or if there is no way to just retrieve any and all items from a table.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `QueryAsync` and `ScanAsync` are just [async-style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) methods that map to the DynamoDB [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) and [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) operations.

You should be able to scan all items in your table using something like this:

```
var conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
// you can add scan conditions, or leave empty
var allDocs = await context.ScanAsync<Item>(conditions).GetRemainingAsync();
```

I recommend starting with the documentation for the [Scan API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html). It will explain the actual API without any client specifics. You will learn about paging, filter expressions etc. Then, if you're not familiar with async/await, read up on that. Finally put them together and you should be able to use QueryAsync and ScanAsync in your own application.

Comment: That worked, thank you for the help and the reading material!

Comment: Also, am I using the correct implementation of DynamoDB in my controller? 

Like should I be creating an instance of the DynamoDBContext in the controller with the injected instance of IAmazonDynamoDB, or should I just be using the injected IAmazonDynamoDB to perform all the operations?

Comment: That’s a good question. I would inject the context into the controller, unless there is a good reason not to.

Comment: yeah I think the context is definitely easier to work with. To instantiate an instance of the context, tho, I need an instance of the client, right? I know the IAmazonDynamoDB interface is an implementation of the client and can be passed in when instantiating the context. So could I do all of this in the ConfigureServices method of my web API and add the context as a Singleton?

Comment: Adding another comment because I feel like that last one was a little confusing. Basically, I am asking if creating a new instance of DynamoDBContext using the injected IAmazonDynamoDB client, and within my controllers constructor, like what I am doing above, is the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: I recommend starting a separate thread as that is a completely different question. Not to be pedantic, but a) it might actually help other people searching for the same (as opposed to these comments) and b) I'm actually not sure - I think you might actually get better answers on a new question that focuses on that problem specifically

Comment: Ah gotcha, I will start a new thread then! Thank you for the help in this one